# How to make Android views shape other than rectangular

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I'm dealing with collision detection with some animated views and I'm animating some alpha image views. What's happening is that the collision detection is triggered even when the second object is on the transparent part of the ImageView when it's apparently not touching it but the ImageView container is rectangular box which exceeds the image bounds.

How can I detect when it touches the drawn part of the image or making the container a triangle?

Here's how Im detecting collision between two views:

```
public boolean checkCollision(View v1, View v2) {
    if (v1 == null || v2 == null) {
        log.e("Views must not be null");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Views mut be not null");
    }
    Rect R1 = new Rect();
    v1.getHitRect(R1);
    Rect R2 = new Rect();
    v2.getHitRect(R2);
    return Rect.intersects(R1, R2);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that kind of collision detection? If this is about a game logic or similar, there are other, more suitable ways to do that, for example like OpenGL or game frameworks.

Comment: @mcwise Yes is about a basic game, but the only constraint is to don't have any framework to make it as more lightweight as possible. Do you know any third party library that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing is to do an initial check of the bounding boxes just to see if you need to perform a more accurate checking. This step is optional if you only have a few objects colliding, but if you have a lot of them it will save a lot of performance.
If you do need to do a further check, make points around the image where you know there is solid texture and then check for a collision with those points. I can try and get you some code for this if you would like, but check out this question here which explains things in depth.
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30866/collision-detection-with-non-rectangular-images